# How do I create a factory_boy Factory that generates all fields automatically?

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm trying to migrate Django code from [milkman](https://github.com/ccollins/milkman) to [factory_boy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Suppose I have a model:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
```

I write a factory:

```
import factory

class BlogPostFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
```

However, factory_boy generates invalid values for these fields by default:

```
In [17]: bp = BlogPostFactory.build()

In [18]: print "title: %r content: %r number: %r" % (bp.title, bp.content, bp.number)
title: u'' content: u'' number: None

In [19]: bp.full_clean()
ValidationError: {'content': [u'This field cannot be blank.'], 'number': [u'This field cannot be null.'], 'title': [u'This field cannot be blank.']}
```

However, milkman can generate values for these fields automatically:

```
In [22]: bp = milkman.deliver(BlogPost)

In [23]: print "title: %r content: %r number: %r" % (bp.title, bp.content, bp.number)
title: 'A8pLAni9xSTY93QJzSi5yY8SGQikL7YGrcTZVViAFS72eqG2bLWHSh0lNLSA2FbH7kSCXDktCQxUO288HTXdYUcRNUikoH4LQ4QHmy6XRwrRzbbmwXL6pLW7tapJM3FTpx8oBbTUw7nCOZew73xjWsID666FKh05ychptiF2peEZHdQd6gnHqXtFkL5kyEIhFvinOCmS' content: 'RUcSHCxs' number: -709949545
```

I know that factory_boy provides [fuzzy attributes](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fuzzy.html), but you have to explicitly use them or [use tons of model/field reflection](https://gist.github.com/tobiasmcnulty/6232216).

Is it possible to create a Factory with factory_boy such that all fields are automatically populated with legal values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Factory Boy auto generate Django model field values like Model Mommy does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545424/can-factory-boy-auto-generate-django-model-field-values-like-model-mommy-does)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Extra Fields:

http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orms.html#extra-fields