# Can Factory Boy auto generate Django model field values like Model Mommy does?

Tags: model, django-testing, factory-boy

By using [Model Mommy](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy), you don't have to set every Model field you use, Model Mommy will automatically set them for you.

but in [Factory Boy](https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy), if you want to use some field in the test, you have to explicitly set the value for them in ModelFactory class.

My question is: Can Factory Boy auto generate Model field values like Model Mommy does?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, Factory Boy does not currently have a way to generate values based on the attribute types defined on the database model without having to define a Factory Boy generator of some sort.

Sounds like a good feature request however.

Comment: There is **django-factory_boy**, however. (Yes: one dash, one underscore.) It aims at building basic factories automatically for Django ORM model classes. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-factory_boy

Comment: Hi, Lutz Prechelt, Can django-factory_boy automatically  self define Model Factory?

Comment: Does not seem to do that @GoTop.  Seems to only do it for some of the built in models. :-(

Comment: There's an open issue for this here: https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/836